# How can I make sure that newly installed packages will not interfere with existing pipeline?

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables

I am fairly new to Linux and I need some advice regarding downloading packages. On the server that I use there are 2 pipelines that were developed by a software developer who has left and unfortunately I do not have the experience he has so I am struggling a bit with making changes.

I recently had to download a software to the server which I did and it seems to be working. However, there is an optional report I can get from that software but it needs some python packages. The manual says to install them like shown below:

```
sudo apt install python3 python3-pip libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev
pip3 install numpy bokeh bs4
```

I am a bit worried about making changes to python in case it interferes with the pipelines even though each pipeline has its own environment. Is there a way to make sure that I can avoid that? Also, if I install numpy, bokeh, bs4 will I be able to uninstall them if they cause an issue? Finally, since I already have Python 3.6.8 on the server should I just do the `pip3 install numpy bokeh bs4` step?

Thank you

Comment: I wouldn't recommend testing if things break by installing libraries on a production system.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#creating-a-virtual-environment) that will allows you to isolate your project from each other. More details in this page

With virtualenv, you can have one project relying on numpy 1.19 and another one with numpy 1.20 for example.